# What’s the difference between Pandas plot.density and plot.kde?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a the difference between the Pandas `plot.density()` and `plot.kde()` function?

Comment: i think its the same. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.density.html refer to the same source-code as i see...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Pandas API Reference, there is no difference between [**`plot.density()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.density.html) and [**`plot.kde()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html), other than their name. These 2 functions do exactly the same thing.

As mentioned by @RichieK in the comments, both API Reference pages take you to the same [**source code**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L3268-L3310) when you click on `[source]` in the top right corner of the page. Thus confirming the functions are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, in the source code you can find :

```
density = kde
```

See here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e8093ba372f9adfe79439d90fe74b0b5b6dea9d6/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1456